# Can't run rsync as root

Tags: server, permissions, rsync

So I recently set up a new installation of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I'm trying to migrate my Zimbra Server to it, and in preparation for this I need to rsync quite a bit of data to the new Server (destination), from the old Server (source). When I try to run rsync as root from the source server, it will prompt me for the root password on the destination server. Every time I put in the root password for the destination server I get "Permission Denied".

I'm using the same exact password as when I'm on the destination server and I enter sudo su. When I do this on the destination server, the password works just fine. Any ideas?

Comment: By default `sudo` requires the invoking user's password, not the root password (which is disabled by default, as is password-based SSH login for root)

Comment: Thank you for the help. I guess I didn't truly realize the difference. When I was trying to rsync I was getting prompted for root's password which I apparently didn't set. Setting that seems to have fixed my issue. Thanks!

Comment: OK glad you found a solution - you might want to look at using rsync+ssh with key-based authentication for root as an alternative